# Apple's own Swift documentation seems wrong about dynamicType vs compile-time type

Tags: swift, dynamic, types, swift2, xcode7

Referencing:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

We have:

```
class SomeBaseClass {
    class func printClassName() {
        print("SomeBaseClass")
    }
}
class SomeSubClass: SomeBaseClass {
    override class func printClassName() {
        print("SomeSubClass")
    }
}
let someInstance: SomeBaseClass = SomeSubClass()
// The compile-time type of someInstance is SomeBaseClass,
// and the runtime type of someInstance is SomeBaseClass
someInstance.dynamicType.printClassName()
// prints "SomeSubClass"
```

> Use the identity operators (=== and !==) to test whether an instance’s runtime type is the same as its compile-time type.

```
if someInstance.dynamicType === someInstance.self {
    print("The dynamic type of someInstance is SomeBaseCass") 
} 
else {
    print("The dynamic type of someInstance isn't SomeBaseClass") 
}
```

but `someInstance.self` appears to refer to the *object*, not the *object's compile-time type*, as claimed by the documentation. In fact in Xcode 7.2, the test does not evaluate to true even when we initialize `someInstance` as `SomeBaseClass`.

It does not inspire confidence that the docs have a typo (SomeBaseCass).

The only way I can find to make the "true" clause fire is the mutation:

```
if someInstance.dynamicType == SomeBaseClass.self { ... }
```

which is interesting but misses the fully dynamic run-time type-checking capability that the flawed Apple docs are trying to show.

Who's wrong and how to resolve?

Comment: You can [file bugs](http://bugreport.apple.com) against the docs (it's not just for software)... they're pretty good about correcting reported errors.

Comment: Bug filed as #24026098.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a typo — kudos to you. That section is about Metatype type and they use type_name.self throughout the section except that very line.

Other than that dynamicType works as advertised — nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

i have doubts about

```
let someInstance: SomeBaseClass = SomeSubClass()
// The compile-time type of someInstance is SomeBaseClass,
// and the runtime type of someInstance is SomeBaseClass
someInstance.dynamicType.printClassName()
// prints "SomeSubClass"
```

and the runtime type of someInstance should BE [SomeSubClass],